# Why second request fail? (do not pass CORS)

Tags: nginx, cors, http-headers

When I make CORS request from 127.0.0.1:

```
        return jQuery.ajax({
            'type': 'GET',
            'url': url,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            ContentType: 'application/json',
        });
```

Then everything is OK:

[image]

But when I change first letter of `ContentType` to lowercase as next:

```
        return jQuery.ajax({
            'type': 'GET',
            'url': url,
            xhrFields: {
                withCredentials: true
            },
            contentType: 'application/json',
        });
```

Then request is failed:

[image]

I suppose that nginx compares headers case sensitively.
Is this a case? or something different happened... =(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The point is that your browser doesn't send `Content-Type: application/json` in the second case. The NGINX isn't involved in that at all, your browser sends the `Content-Type` in both cases, but when you give the `ContentType` parameter to jQuery, it's being silently ignored. The correct parameter is `contentType`, not `ContentType`.